# How to automatically combine multipe Haskell modules into one

Tags: haskell, module

Assume I have a few Haskell modules, and I want to run them in an environment that requires the whole program to be entered as a single module (e.g. static analyzers, programming competition websites etc.). This might also be interesting for performance, to see if GHC does better when it sees all code of the application at once.

Disregarding corner cases like differences in the set of language pragmas, or orphan instances, it seems plausible that there is a way to combine these modules into one (and I could probably do it by hand).

But is there a better, automated way?

Comment: I am not aware of an automated way, though I believe this argument appeared on the Haskell café ML a very long time ago. Anyway, to automate this you need some renaming to avoid clashes.

Comment: It might be reasonably easy to implement this with [`haskell-names`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/haskell-names).

Comment: I started some proof-of-conceot here: https://github.com/nomeata/hs-all-in-one.